# Separability of $A \subseteq C$ implies separability of $B \subseteq C$, where $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, projective-module

For commutative rings $R \subseteq S$,
recall that $S$ is separable over $R$, if $S$ is a projective $S \otimes_R S$-module. (via $f: S \otimes_R S \to S$ given by: $f(s_1 \otimes_R s_2)=s_1s_2$).

My question:

> Assume $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ are commutative rings, such that $C$ is separable over $A$. Is $C$ separable over $B$?

Can anyone please help me with the proof?

Adjamagbo claims that this implies that $C$ is separable over $B$,
but I am not able to prove this.

Adjamagbo's claim appears on page 92 (13) in: 
"*On separable algebras over a UFD and the Jacobian conjecture in any characteristic*", in Automorphisms of affine spaces, A. van den Essen (ed.),
Kluwer Academic Publishers, 1995.

Comment: Can't you project down the separability idempotent for $C/A$ onto $C \otimes_B C$ (using the projection $C \otimes_A C \to C \otimes_B C$) ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint! Denote $f_{AC}: C \otimes_A C \to C$, and $f_{BC}: C \otimes_B C \to C$. Denote the separability idempotent for $C/A$ by $e_{AC}$, and denote its image in $C \otimes_B C$ by $\bar{e}$.  How I show that $\bar{e}$ satisfies the two conditions of a separability idempotent?

Comment: Namely, how to show that: (1) $f_{BC}(\bar{e})=1$. (2) $Kerf_{BC}\bar{e}=0$.

Comment: I don't recall there being a kernel condition in the definition of a separability idempotent. There was a commutativity-like condition, though.

Comment: I have found your commutativity condition in Lemma 2.1 in the following paper of Auslander and Buchsbaum "On ramification theory in noetherian rings" http://people.brandeis.edu/~buchsbau/miscpapers/024.pdf It is actually equivalent to my above condition, since the kernel is of the form $\{1\otimes c- c \otimes 1\}$.

Comment: Of course, I meant the kernel is generated by $\{1 \otimes c- c \otimes 1\}$. Anyway, I have now taken from the library "Separable algebras over commutative rings" by DeMeyer and Ingraham (Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Springer-Verlag, 1971), and they prove what I have asked, in their Proposition 1.12.

Comment: Now I see the source of the confusion. I don't know why anyone would define separability using a kernel instead of an explicit equation; you are right in that the kernel definition doesn't make (2) obvious. Glad this has been cleared up!

Comment: NB: I think a reference for separability more canonical than the Auslander-Buchsbaum paper you've cited is Auslander-Goldman, *The Brauer group of a commutative ring*, http://www.ams.org/tran/1960-097-03/S0002-9947-1960-0121392-6/S0002-9947-1960-0121392-6.pdf . I think the proof of your claim is implicit in the first paragraph of the proof of Theorem 2.3 there.

Comment: Thanks! (I knew about Auslander-Goldman's paper, though I have not tried to read it, so thanks for the hint. Actually, that paper, Auslander-Buchsbaum's paper and DeMeyer-Ingraham's book, are all listed in Wang's paper: "Jacobian criterion for separability").

Comment: @darijgrinberg: If you wish to post your answer with the commutativity condition, I will accept it (but you don't have to; only if you want. BTW, the above book of DeMeyer-Ingraham leaves the proof for the reader...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a canonical epimorphism $C\otimes_AC\to C\otimes_BC$ and its kernel annihilates $C$. Since $C$ is a projective $C\otimes_AC$-module it follows that it is also a projective $C\otimes_BC$-module.