# $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ with $A \subseteq C$ separable and $pd_{B \otimes_A B}(B) = \infty$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, projective-module

Assume $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ are commutative rings such that $C$ is separable over $A$, namely $C$ is a projective $C \otimes_A C$-module.

Separability of $C$ over $A$ does not imply separability of $B$ over $A$. In other words, it can happen that $pd_{C \otimes_A C}(C)=0$ and $pd_{B \otimes_A B}(B) > 0$.

Can one find rings $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ with $pd_{C \otimes_A C}(C)=0$ and $pd_{B \otimes_A B}(B)= \infty$? (I guess yes), or if $pd_{C \otimes_A C}(C)=0$, then necessarily $pd_{B \otimes_A B}(B)< \infty$?

(Notice that 
[separability of $C$ over $A$ implies separability of $C$ over $B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312743/separability-of-a-subseteq-c-implies-separability-of-b-subseteq-c-where)).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Given $k$ a field, the algebras $M_n(k),n>1$ contain nonseparable subalgebras like the algebra $T_n(k)$ of upper triangular matrices (which is not semisimple, so not separable).

Comment: Thanks! (1) How one shows that $pd_{T_n(k) \otimes_k T_n(k)}(T_n(k)) = \infty$? (2) If $R$ is a commutative ring, then $M_n(R)$ is a separable $R$-algebra (page 41, Example 2, in the book of DeMeyer and Ingraham about separable algebras). I guess one can similarly show that  $pd_{T_n(R) \otimes_R T_n(R)}(T_n(R)) = \infty$?

Comment: That dimensión is not infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be a field, let $C$ be a matrix algebra over $k$, and let $B$ be any subalgebra of $C$ isomorphic to $k[x]/(x^2)$. $B$ could be the subalgebra of $C$ generated by any non-zero matrix with zero square.

Comment: Can one give an example with field extensions? Finite extensions won't work since the separability degree is multiplicative.

Comment: If C/A is a separable field extension,  then every subextension is also separable. This is because separability of field extensions can be checked element by element.

Comment: Right. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez thank you very much! Can you please add a short explanation why $pd_{C \otimes_A C}(C)=0$ and $pd_{B \otimes_A B}(B) = \infty$?

Comment: Matrix algebras are one of the simplest examples of separable algebras; that they are separable should be proven in pretty much every textbook on the subject! On the other hand, for B you can, for example, compute $Tor^{B\otimes_AB}(B,B)$ and see that it is nonzero in every degree: this implies at once that the projective dimension of B as a bimodule is infinite.

Comment: Thanks! (1)  Indeed, the proof that a matrix algebra over a commutative ring is separable can be found, for example, in "Separable algebras over commutative rings" by DeMeyer and Ingraham, page 41, Example 2. (2) A separable algebra over a field is finite dimensional (page 48, Corollary 2.2, in the above book). Do you have an example where $A$ is not a field (and $C$ is not a finitely generated $A$-module)? Can one prove that if $C$ and $B$ are finitely generated $A$-modules, then $pd_{B \otimes_A B}(B)$ must be finite? Thanks!

Comment: (maybe I should ask the last question as a new question?)

Comment: Don't ask a new question: find a projective resolution!

Comment: :) So you are saying that the following claim is true: Assume $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ are commutative rings, $C$ is separable over $A$, $C$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, then  $pd_{B \otimes_A B}(B) < \infty$. If so, I do not understand why in your example $pd_{B \otimes_A B}(B)=\infty$. What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you think I said that?  I didn't: it is false, and my example, precisely, shows that it is false!

Comment: If you replace in my example a field by $\mathbb Z$ exactly the sam conclusion holds. If you want $C$ to be non-finitely generated over $\mathbb Z$ just localize at any prime, for example.

Comment: I thought you meant: "Don't ask a new question: find a finite projective resolution!". And what I meant in: "If so, I do not understand why in your example $pd_{B \otimes_A B}(B)=\infty$" is that it contradicts the claim about finite dimensionality (that I thought you said was true). Thank you very much for your answer and comments!